# Is there a widely used util/library method in Java to tell if all elements in a collection are unique?

Tags: java, collections, unique

I'm looking for a method that, if it were in the standard library, would probably be something like `boolean Collections#areAllUnique(Collection)`. I want a method that returns true iff there are no duplicates in the collection.

Obviously, this would return true for any (properly implemented) Set.

It's also easy to write yourself, as something like `collection.size() == new HashSet(collection).size()`. However, there are a few reasons I'd still like to see it as a one-line library method:

1. It's easier :)
2. The above is not as efficient as it could be; the method could avoid building the entire second set if it detects any duplicates.

A good implementation might look like

```
public static <T> boolean areAllUnique(Collection<T> collection) {
  if (collection instanceof Set) {
    return true;
  }
  HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<>(collection.size());
  for (T t : collection) {
    if (set.contains(t)) {
      return false;
    }
    set.add(t);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Is there a method like this somewhere in the Java standard library or any of the well-known libraries out there (Guava, etc.)?

Comment: Your good implementation suggests that you think there's a common use case for knowing whether a generic collection is distinct. If efficiency is a real concern, then a generic library method wouldn't be enough, if efficiency isn't a concern then a generic library method isn't *that* useful. I.e. in my opinion you're overestimating the need for such a method, but you're free to look around Guava and other libraries. I'd be surprised if *someone* hadn't written one. I seem to recall seeing something like that somewhere.

Comment: And the method would only be relevant in collections that support duplicates, like lists.

Comment: Nit: `if (!set.add(t))` is better than `contains/add`.

Comment: I think I saw a particularly cheeky way of doing it, something like `collection.stream().allMatch(new HashSet<>()::add)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that no such method exists in Guava.

Comment: Also nit: you don't need `T`, `Collection<?>`/`HashSet<Object>` is adequate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that no such method exists in Guava.

Your method is mostly fine; I would make a couple of tweaks to it to make it marginally cleaner/more efficient:

```
// T doesn't really do anything. A wildcard is sufficient.
public static boolean areAllUnique(Collection<?> collection) {
  if (collection instanceof Set) {
    return true;
  }
  HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<>(collection.size());
  for (Object t : collection) {
    // add only returns true if the set is changed, so you don't need to
    // do contains/add separately.
    if (!set.add(t)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

If you want to make the API designers cry (because predicates should be stateless), you can also do the same thing more concisely:

```
return collection instanceof Set
    || collection.stream().allMatch(new HashSet<>(collection.size())::add);
```

Comment: Since you removed `<T>`, you also have to use `Object` for the loop variable. Besides that, you may consider a pre-test like `if(collection.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.DISTINCT)) return true;` This may not only handle `Set` implementations but also other cases where an implementation knows beforehand that all elements are unique (and reports it).